# UWP - A debugger is attached to .exe but not configured

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm developing Windows Store App (UWP) and I have a problem with native code - I have this message.[image]

This exception throw after this code fired for second or third time.

```
if(ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailable)
{
    if(init != null)
    {
        init.ProjectionViewPageControl.StartViewInUse();
        await ProjectionManager.StopProjectingAsync(MainPage.SecondaryViewId, thisViewId);
        init.ProjectionViewPageControl.StopViewInUse();
        rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl = null;
    }

    if(rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl == null)
    {
        //First, create a new, blank view
        var thisDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
        await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl = ViewLifetimeControl.CreateForCurrentView();                //ViewLifetimeControl is a wrapper to make sure the view is closed only when the app is done with it

            //Assemble some data necessary for the new page
            init = new ProjectionViewPageInitializationData();
            init.MainDispatcher = thisDispatcher;
            init.ProjectionViewPageControl = rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl;
            init.MainViewId = thisViewId;
                                            //Note that the view will not become visible until "StartProjectingAsync" is called
            var rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ProjectionViewPage), init);
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
        });
    }

    try
    {
        rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl.StartViewInUse();    // Start/StopViewInUse are used to signal that the app is interacting with the view, so it shouldn't be closed yet, even if the user loses access to it
        await ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync(rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl.Id, thisViewId);    // Show the view on a second display (if available) or on the primary display
        rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl.StopViewInUse();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

`ProjectionViewPage` opens, everything working But I don't know what's wrong. This exception thrown after different time, after different times of page opened and closed. I have no idea what's going wrong.

**UPD**
Problem occurs when `ProjectionViewPage` has `MediaElement` control.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to change the debugger type from Managed Only (default) to Mixed. It won't fix your exception, but at least you can trace it with the debugger now :)

[image]