# CodecQuery.FindAllAsync crashes through try/catch when querying Audio codecs without subtype

Tags: c#, .net, audio, uwp, windows-10-universal

[Blank project repo with problematic code](https://github.com/datvm/UwpCrashQueryAudioCodecs)

I have the following code for querying all the supported Audio codec following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/codec-query) using [`CodecQuery.FindAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.codecquery.findallasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Media_Core_CodecQuery_FindAllAsync_Windows_Media_Core_CodecKind_Windows_Media_Core_CodecCategory_System_String_)

```
            try
            {
                var query = new CodecQuery();
                var queryResult = await query.FindAllAsync(CodecKind.Audio, CodecCategory.Encoder, "");

                var subTypes = queryResult
                    .SelectMany(q => q.Subtypes)
                    .ToHashSet();

                // Other codes
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }
```

As the documentation mentioned,

> To specify that all codecs of the specified kind and category should be returned, regardless of what media subtypes are supported, specify an empty string ("") or null for this parameter.

For empty string "", it works for `CodecKind.Video` but not for `Audio` (for both `CodecCategory` of `Encoder` or `Decoder`). If I specify a subtype, then it does not crash, for example:

```
var queryResult = await query.FindAllAsync(CodecKind.Audio, CodecCategory.Encoder, CodecSubtypes.AudioFormatMP3);
```

What is strange about that is that even though I have a try/catch with generic `Exception`, the app just crashes through that one and show this instead:

[image]

I have tried restarting Windows, uninstall the UWP app and make a clean build. What is happening? How do I query all available audio codecs?

Update: after changing Debug setting, I could trace the error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDCE5FD759 (KernelBase.dll) in ******.exe: 0xC0000002:  The requested operation is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

After my testing, the content of this document is correct. When I set “” for the third parameter to find all audio codecs, the code works well. So there is not an error in this document.

You could choose the **Debug** options, and change **Debugger type** from **Managed Only** to **Mixed**. It won't fix your exception, but you can trace it with the debugger. You could refer to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373043/uwp-a-debugger-is-attached-to-exe-but-not-configured) to get more information.

Comment: Thanks I will check later, but one note, the doc is correct about empty string (""). Exception is thrown if it is `null` though. Not too much but it's just for consistency. I submitted a doc issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2974

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated the question with the error I traced back. Seem like something is wrong in there.

Comment: When I set null for the third parameter, it really reported an exception, but that shows “System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'” 
I have searched for KERNELBASE.DLL errors, it is always in strong connection with UI thread access exceptions. Did you do something similar?

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion, just ignore the `null` value for now, I am using empty string and the problem occurs when the third parameter is `""`. I have already reported [that issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2974). I also see the same answer in MS Q&A forum, I thought posting there would help because I was led there by the Github issue, sorry for double posting, let's use this one in the mean time :)

Comment: From the Github issue, he also suggested me to use an empty project, I still have the problem so I guess it's something wrong with my PC, because both you and him cannot reproduce it. Maybe something's wrong with one of the codec on my PC since the exception is `The requested operation is not implemented`? Anyway I can give you diagnostic data so you can debug it? Unfortunately right now I have no other computer, and I am worried that other users' PC may have the same problem.

Comment: We are consulting other engineers for your question. There may be some delay.